# Re-writing several individual SQL query's into one

Tags: php, mysql, string, count, pivot

I have a database where I'm displaying numbers of rows from different columns of a table, as statistics for a site. In pure text, it looks like this (english translation):

"At the moment, there are **86** questions registered. **16** are in the category of history, **6** in the category of geography."

My PHP script is pretty simple:

```
$question_query = mysqli_query($conn, 'SELECT Q_id FROM questions');  
$question_result = mysqli_num_rows($question_query);

$historie_query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT Q_id FROM questions WHERE category LIKE '%Historie%'");  
$historie_result = mysqli_num_rows($historie_query);

$geografi_query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT Q_id FROM questions WHERE category LIKE '%Geografi%'");  
$geografi_result = mysqli_num_rows($geografi_query);

echo '<h3>' . 'For øyeblikket er det ' . '<b>' . $question_result . '</b>' . ' spørsmål i databasen:' . '</h3>';
echo '<ul>' . '<li>' . '<b>' . $historie_result . '</b>' . ' historie-spørsmål.' . '</li>' ;
echo '<li>' . '<b>' . $geografi_result . '</b>' . ' geografi-spørsmål.' . '</li>' . '</ul>';
```

This works well, but right now it's only doing 3 queries. In the future, it will probably be about 10 or 15 queries.

I've tried to join these into one, but it's only outputting the first query:

```
$query =  "SELECT Q_id FROM questions"; 
        "SELECT Q_id FROM questions WHERE category LIKE '%Historie%'"; 
        "SELECT Q_id FROM questions WHERE category LIKE '%Geografi%'";

$result = mysqli_query ($conn, $query);
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

print_r ($count);
```

I figured a while loop might be able to solve that, but when I replace the print_r with the while loop, I get an undefined variable error for the different row counts ($question_count, $historie_count, $geografi_count):

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $row[0] = $question_count;
    $row[1] = $historie_count;
    $row[2] = $geografi_count;

    print_r ($question_count . '</br>' . $historie_count . '</br>' . $geografi_count);

}
```

How could I go about making this into one query? And, is that desirable, or is it better to keep the queries separated?

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: For executing multi-query, you should check this https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    count(*) question_count, 
    sum(category like '%Historie%') historie_count, 
    sum(category like '%Geografi%') geografi_count
from questions
```

Comment: That would be a great solution! How do you do that in PHP?

Comment: The above is a plain sql statement, so however you would normally pass an sql statement along with your current project's structure. That said, also consider perhaps using a prepared statement and parameterizing the `LIKE` condition